# How to change a learning rate for Adam in TF2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How to change the learning rate of Adam optimizer, while learning is progressing in TF2? 
There some answers floating around, but applicable to TF1, e.g. using feed_dict.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using custom training loop (instead of `keras.fit()`), you can simply do:

```py
new_learning_rate = 0.01 
my_optimizer.lr.assign(new_learning_rate)
```

Comment: No! It won't be used 'while learning is progressing': see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737875/keras-change-learning-rate

Answer (score 18):

You can read and assign the learning rate via a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/). So you can use something like this:

```py
class LearningRateReducerCb(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    old_lr = self.model.optimizer.lr.read_value()
    new_lr = old_lr * 0.99
    print("\nEpoch: {}. Reducing Learning Rate from {} to {}".format(epoch, old_lr, new_lr))
    self.model.optimizer.lr.assign(new_lr)
```

Which, for example, using the [MNIST demo](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) can be applied like this:

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks=[LearningRateReducerCb()], epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

giving output like this:

```
Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/5
59744/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2969 - accuracy: 0.9151
Epoch: 0. Reducing Learning Rate from 0.0010000000474974513 to 0.0009900000877678394
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 92us/sample - loss: 0.2965 - accuracy: 0.9152
Epoch 2/5
59488/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1421 - accuracy: 0.9585
Epoch: 1. Reducing Learning Rate from 0.0009900000877678394 to 0.000980100128799677
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/sample - loss: 0.1420 - accuracy: 0.9586
Epoch 3/5
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1056 - accuracy: 0.9684
Epoch: 2. Reducing Learning Rate from 0.000980100128799677 to 0.0009702991228550673
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/sample - loss: 0.1056 - accuracy: 0.9684
Epoch 4/5
59520/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0856 - accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch: 3. Reducing Learning Rate from 0.0009702991228550673 to 0.0009605961386114359
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 89us/sample - loss: 0.0857 - accuracy: 0.9733
Epoch 5/5
59712/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0734 - accuracy: 0.9772
Epoch: 4. Reducing Learning Rate from 0.0009605961386114359 to 0.0009509901865385473
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 87us/sample - loss: 0.0733 - accuracy: 0.9772
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 43us/sample - loss: 0.0768 - accuracy: 0.9762
[0.07680597708942369, 0.9762]
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears that I do not need even callback, I just need to execute optimizer.lr.assign(new_value)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helps. If my answer was helpful to you then you can always upvote and/or accept.. :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use low-level control and not the `fit` functionality with callbacks, have a look at [`tf.optimizers.schedules`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules). Here's some example code:

```
train_steps = 25000
lr_fn = tf.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(1e-3, train_steps, 1e-5, 2)
opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(lr_fn)
```

This would decay the learning rate from 1e-3 to 1e-5 over 25000 steps with a power-2 polynomial decay.

Note:

- This doesn't really "store" a learning rate as in the other answer, but rather the learning rate is now a function that will be called every time it is needed to compute the current learning rate.
- `Optimizer` instances have an internal step counter that will count up by one each time `apply_gradients` is called (as far as I can tell...). This allows for this procedure to work properly when using it in a low-level context (usually with `tf.GradientTape`)
- Unfortunately this feature is not well-documented (docs just say that the learning rate argument has to be a float or tensor...) but it works. You can also write your own decay schedules. I think they just need to be functions that take in some current "state" of the optimizer (probably number of training steps) and return a float to be used as learning rate.

Comment: This is really hard to find but the most elegant solution imho
assigning it during the loop is very ugly

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 solutions:

- The [LearningRateScheduler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler), which is the Callback solution mentioned in the other answer.
- The Module: [tf.keras.optimizers.schedules](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules) with a couple of prebuilt methods, which is also mentioned above.
- And a fully custom solution is to extend [tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule) (part of the previous module)

Here is an example from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#optimizer):

```
class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, d_model, warmup_steps=4000):
        super(CustomSchedule, self).__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.d_model = tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32)

        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

    def __call__(self, step):
        arg1 = tf.math.rsqrt(step)
        arg2 = step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5)

        return tf.math.rsqrt(self.d_model) * tf.math.minimum(arg1, arg2)
```

And you pass it to your optimizer:

```
learning_rate = CustomSchedule(d_model)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, 
                                     epsilon=1e-9)
```

This way, the CustomSchedule will be part of your graph and it will update the Learning rate while your model is training.

Comment: What is `d_model`?

Comment: @Nerxis The model where you have set you're optimizer on

Comment: Thanks, I just found this in the example, I think it would be worth of adding this directly to your answer. You just copied content of the example but without whole context it's not clear.