# Setting adaptable learning rate for Adam without using callbacks

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am exploring the translation model with attention from Tensorflow docs - [NMT with Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention) . Here in TF 2.0, optimizer is defined as

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
```

How do I set a learning rate in this case? Is it just initializing the argument like below? How do I set an adaptable learning rate?

```
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
```

In the [NMT with Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention) model, they dont use Keras to define the model and I could not use Callbacks or 'model.fit' like below:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks=[LearningRateReducerCb()], epochs=5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a learning rate for Adam in TF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301698/how-to-change-a-learning-rate-for-adam-in-tf2)

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience with NMT, but regarding the link you have provided, the best would be probably to use [LearningRateSchedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule) that can be directly used as learning rate parameter in any optimizer (e.g. in Adam in your example). The process would be following:

1. Define your adaptive learning rate schedule (e.g. `AdaptiveLRSchedule` that would inherit from `LearningRateSchedule` and would implement any adaptive learning rate you prefer, similarly like [in this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#optimizer)).
2. Instantiate your object - `learning_rate = AdaptiveLRSchedule(your_parameters)`
3. Use it as a learning rate in Adam optimizer - `optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)`
4. Keep the rest as is in the example (`optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables)` should now correctly apply gradients and use adaptive learning rate according to your definition).

Note, that instead of defining your own class in the first step you can use one of schedules that already exists in TF like [ExponencialDecay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay).

The second option would be to manually set `lr` in `train_step` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention#training) in your example). After backpropagation (see `apply_gradients` method in (4) above that comes from your example) you can directly set your `lr`. This can be achieved via `optimizer.learning_rate.assign(new_lr)` where `new_lr` would be new learning rate coming from your adaptive lr function that you have to define (something like `new_lr = adaptive_lr(optimizer.learning_rate)` where `adaptive_lr` would implement it).