# Is there a way to reset the learning rate on each fold while employing the ReduceLROnPlateau callback of Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

As the title is self-descriptive, I'm looking for a way to reset the `learning rate (lr)` on each fold. The `ReduceLROnPlateau` callback of `Keras` manages the `lr`.

Comment: Reset the learning rate to what? A default value? Also by fold do you mean step of an epoch?

Comment: Yes, reset to the initial value. By fold I mean each `k`-fold of the dataset, while looping `k` times on the dataset.

Comment: So calling the .fit() method iteratively on each fold (in a for loop) wouldn't work?

Comment: Surely it works but the training instinctively continues from the last updated value of `lr`. But I need to reset it at the start of the training of each `k`-fold.

Comment: How is your training set up? Is a fold a batch?

Comment: It is `5`-fold and batch size is `64`. The whole dataset consists of `11,088` samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no reproducible example I can only make a suggestion. If you take a look at the source code of [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.6.0/keras/callbacks.py#L2581-L2701) you can get some inspiration and create a custom callback to reset the learning rate on the beginning of training:

```
class ResetLR(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    default_lr = 0.1
    previous_lr = self.model.optimizer.lr.read_value()
    if previous_lr!=defaul_lr:
      print("Resetting learning rate from {} to {}".format(previous_lr, default_lr))
      self.model.optimizer.lr.assign(default_lr)
```

So with this callback you train using a for loop:

```
custom_callback = ResetLR()
for fold in folds:
  model.fit(...., callbacks=[custom_callback])
```

If this does not work (due to tensorflow versions) you can try assigning the default learning rate using the `tf.keras.backend` like so:

```
class ResetLR(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    default_lr = 0.1
    previous_lr = float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))
    if previous_lr!=default_lr:
      print("Resetting learning rate from {} to {}".format(previous_lr, default_lr))
      tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, default_lr)
```

Also I would suggest taking a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301698/how-to-change-a-learning-rate-for-adam-in-tf2), for more references.

Answer (score 2):

below is a custom callback that will do the job. At the start of training, the callback prompts the user to enter the value of the initial learning rate.

```
class INIT_LR(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__ (self, model): # initialization of the callback
        super(INIT_LR, self).__init__()
        self.model=model
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None): # this runs on the beginning of training
        print('Enter initial learning rate below')
        lr=input('')        
        tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, float(lr)) # set the learning rate in the optimizer
        lr=float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)) # get the current learning rate to insure it is set
        print('Optimizer learning rate set to ', lr)
```

in model.fit set the parameter

```
callbacks = [INIT_LR(model), rlronp]
```

Note: model is the name of your compiled model, and rlronp is the name of your  ReduceLROnPlateau callback. When you run model.fit you will be
prompted with

```
Enter initial learning rate below # printed by the callback
.001  # user entered initial learning rate
Optimizer learning rate set to  0.0010000000474974513 # printed by the callback
```